# ServiceNow KB in Azure cognitive services

Tags: azure, servicenow, azure-cognitive-services, azure-rest-api, servicenow-rest-api

Is there a way to integrate the ServiceNow KB in azure cognitive services? We want to use the ServiceNow KB as a knowledge base for Azure Cognitive.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the use case that you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a corpus Knowledge Base articles located in ServiceNow, you can use the [ITSM Skill](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/samples/itsm/) to surface them to end users.

Here is a recording of an SAP/ServiceNow Bot built for a talk that leveraged Bot Framework and Logic Apps.
https://www.biztalk360.com/integrate-2017-resources/give-bots-connectivity-azure-logic-apps/